# Finding the Configuration State Functions of Atoms

Tags: computational-chemistry, reference-request, configuration-interaction, atomic-physics, graphical-unitary-group-approach

Is there a book or tabulated work where the configuration state functions of atoms have been documented? Just as useful would be information about computer programs that are able to predict the CSFs.

Comment: Didn't know you left hogwarts to study atoms :)

Answer (score 2):

A configuration state function (CSF) is a symmetry-adapted linear combination of Slater determinants. Even for a small basis set, there can be trillions of CSFs. Those will surely not all be tabulated in a book!

However you asked about computer programs to generate CSFs, and some of these are listed at the bottom of [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_state_function).

For atoms there's **[LSGEN](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0010465593900247?via%3Dihub)** by Sturesson and Froese Fischer.

For molecules there's **ALCHEMY II**: A Research Tool for Molecular Electronic Structure and Interactions, by McLean *et al.*

Comment: Assuming I do not just have basis sets but presume to know the exact set of orbitals for my system and additionally want only one specific spin configurations and only be interested in atoms, wouldn't that reduce the number of possible configuration state functions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.